# Passing query data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have been stuck on this problem for too long and would love some help.

On a view people can select two items from two radiobutton lists which returns via a FormMethod.Get to the Index event in HomeController.

These 2 values, 'parts and 'use' are queried to return a result and its passed back to the view via a viewbag. However the viewbag returns a line like { Item = Kona, Price = 400.0000, Quantity = 2 } in the view.

Whereas I want to return each item such as item.Item, Item.Price so I can use them individually.

I have tried everything I can find to no avail. 
Anonymous classes items also throw red errors

View

```
foreach(var item in ViewBag.getstock)
{ //Show it and then make a new line with the <BR/>
    @item < br / >
    //{ Item = Kona, Price = 400.0000, Quantity = 2 } 
}
```

HomeController

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     //this returns the entire query string
     ViewBag.querystring = Request.QueryString;

     //if any keys are in the url from the view
     if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
     {
         //extract them out so that you can use them
         //key = the name such as Part or Use it goes Key & Value this is passed to a Viewbag
         //get(o) is getting the value at place 0, the first value in the url

         ViewBag.querystringvalue0 = Request.QueryString.Get(0);
         ViewBag.querystringvalue1 = Request.QueryString.Get(1);
     }

     //if there is any query string
     if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
     {
         //pass the data to a couple of variables,
         var parts = Request.QueryString.Get(0);
         var use = Request.QueryString.Get(1);

         //put them in a new query and return the results
         ViewBag.getstock = from p in Bikeshopdb.Stocks
         where p.PartName == parts && (p.Road == use || p.Mtn == use || p.Hybrid == use) select new
         {
             p.Item, p.Price, p.Quantity
         };

     }
     return View(Bikeshopdb.Stocks.ToList());
```

Comment: Can you add some view code please - you shouldn't be using QueryString like that in MVC it defeats the purpose, you should be adding the form objects to the parameter of your controller. I would recommend you work through this tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: Hi Rob Here is the relevent view code, its just a simple foreach, but I want to get item.Price, Item.Item etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ViewModel class to hold the query results and pass back to the view. For example:

HomeController

```
public class MatchingStock()
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}

public ActionResult Index()
{

    //...

    var list = 
        (from p in Bikeshopdb.Stocks
        where p.PartName == parts && 
            (p.Road == use || p.Mtn == use || p.Hybrid == use)
        select new MatchingStock() { 
            ID = p.ID, 
            Item = p.Item, 
            Price = p.Price, 
            Quantity = p.Quantity}).ToList();

    ViewBag.getstock = list;

    //...

}
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in (List<MatchingStock>)ViewBag.getstock)
{
    @item.Item @item.Price @item.Quantity
    <br />
}
```

Comment: Viewmodels are now to me, but I get the idea, however it looks like you are still using the HomeController and the View here, where does the viewmodel fit in?

Comment: The Viewmodel is just a class to hold the results of your query in a unique shape for a particular view. I don't believe a query result to an anonymous class can be passed back to a view. Even if it could, how would you be able to cast the ViewBag.getstock in order to iterate through the results? The Viewmodel class could be defined within the Controller class if you want, although that is likely not the best practice.

Comment: Surely this has to be a common situation when you want to extract data from a db and show it in the view? Anyway, thanks for your help, I have made a new class viewmodel and stuck the MatchingStock into it. code is happy (thanks to resharper) :-) , yet view returns 404 Any idea why?

Comment: I think it is common practice to create one ViewModel class per View. Often a view may require data from more than one table. Actually in your case you probably could have passed back the Stock class generated by Linq to the View via the ViewBag. The most important step is the requirement to cast the ViewBag in your view. 404's in MVC generally mean there is something with you URL you are using and there not being a corresponding action/controller and not with the code.